# Is it possible to run Grunt Karma locally?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, karma-runner

Is it possible to run Grunt Karma locally?

Start the Karma server, assign a port to it and then open different browsers on my computer and run tests by inserting the localhost:port?

I have a Github project running Travis and have strange results in some Browsers. I can run the tests locally but only with "virtual" PhantomJS. Would be nice to check my Specs in a real browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I regularly use `karma-chrome-launcher` and know that there is also `karma-firefox-launcher` as well.

In your `karma.conf.js` file, or in your `Gruntfile.js` options area you can define:

```
browsers: ['Phantomjs', 'Chrome'],
```

and then in the plugins section include:

```
plugins: [
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-firefox-launcher',
    'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
]
```

https://github.com/karma-runner has a list of launcher plugins and other useful plugins. There is even a [karma-browserstack-launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-browserstack-launcher), though that wouldn't be local.

Documentation on what you can configure either total in the `Gruntfile.js` or by referencing a `karma.conf.js` in your `Gruntfile.js` can be found:

- https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma
- http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html

I like the functionality of using a `karma.conf.js` file to separate out the majority of my karma config, so in my `Gruntfile.js` I do the following:

```
karma: {
    options: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
    },
    unit: {
        autoWatch: true,
        singleRun: true
    },
    watch: { // still needs watch integration and testing
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        background: true
    }
},
```

Then in my `karma.conf.js` file I follow the base structure shown https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/test/client/karma.conf.js

Comment: Jason, thank you for feedback! Where do I add plugins in the Gruntfile.js? is it under options`? And that is the same as karma.conf.js? because I have no karma.conf.js file...